# Upgrading form Ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3, Should I re-install all gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I would like to avoid re-installing the gems if possible while doing the upgrade from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3. Is there an option as such while using RVM to manage ruby versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can run

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.2 1.9.3
```

this will:

- install latest 1.9.3 (if needed)
- copy all gemsets
- run gem pristine on every single gem and report those that failed
- ask you if you want to delete the old ruby

the step with `gem pristine` is required as there might be changes between rubies that would break stuff - especially that gem creators use internal ruby stuff.

Comment: Grrr! another competing answer that I like more than my own (answer)!  I must be good though so +1 from me !  Basically - "boy that's useful!"

Comment: Just want to add that I had a slight problem when I had multiple version of 1.9.2 installed.  So it is safer to use more specific versions.  <pre>rvm upgrade 1.9.2-p180  1.9.3-p327</pre>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  The gems are installed on top of the specific version so I think you will need to reinstall.  However with rails you should be able to just `bundle install`

Best Practice will also to be to create a gemset at the root of your project.

Here's mine:

```
$ cat .rvmrc 

rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125@my_local_app_name --create
```

Then when you cd into it it will set the ruby and rails versions for you.
You will see a nice green status line showing you that, e.g.

```
Using /Users/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125 with gemset dmworkflow
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for answering. But the steps mentioned by mpapis was what I was after.